# I'm trying to validate my Logistic regression model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

```
X=train.drop('Loan_Status', 1)
y=train.Loan_Status


X=pd.get_dummies(X)
train=pd.get_dummies(train)
test=pd.get_dummies(test)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_cv, y_train, y_cv=train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.3)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

model= LogisticRegression()
model.fit=(X_train, y_train)

LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True, 
                   intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1, 
                   penalty='l2', random_state=1, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001, 
                   verbose=0, warm_start=False)

pred_cv=model.predict(X_cv)
```

But I'm getting this error:

"NotFittedError: This LogisticRegression instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator."

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a syntax issue:

```
model.fit=(X_train, y_train)
```

Should be

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```